# Is there any state-by-state data on approval for LBJ or the Vietnam War?

Tags: united-states, history, public-opinion, data-sources, us-states

I cannot find any data on approval ratings for LBJ on a state by state level.

Comment: This question is better suited to [History SE](https://history.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @RickSmith or maybe [Open Data SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I agree with @RickSmith - it's not off topic here (it's still definitively politics), but the people with the expertise to be able to find an good source for polling data from the 60s are more likely to be over on History than here.

Comment: There are probably select states for which that data is available from polling in state level political races that asked that as an additional question, but the data probably isn't available for all 50 states in a single poll.

Answer (score 1):

State by state approval of Johnson would be hard to find relevant polling information available to the public.   His re-election exploratory committee obviously  felt it would have been abysmal as Johnson declined to enter the Democrat Primaries for '68, thus the most widely statistics from actual election polls would not have listed him (public polling organizations tend not to poll state by state, and party polling tend not to get publicly released).  Clearly the numbers were not there.   1968 was a year that was incredibly bad to Democrats, as Johnson was not the first Democrat to announce his plans to run for the Primaries (it's considered an rare event that a sitting president is running against a primary challenger from his or her own party, and usually a bad sign for the President if they are polling well prior to the primary races).  Then the front runner, Robert Kennedy, was assassinated by Surhan Surhan in 2 month prior to the Democratic National Convention, which was considered a spectacular disaster both inside the building and outside.  Democratic Presidential Nominee, Hurbert Humphrey narrowly beat out candidates supported by democrats who were opposed to the Vietnam War, and Humphrey's Presidential Campaign was marred by a party base that didn't want Johnson and a candidate who was seen as too much like Johnson by the base.  He was further marred in several reliable Democrat states in the deep South (Namely all gulf states excluding Texas and Florida plus Georgia and a faithless elector in North Carolina) that broke for Third Party Candidate George Wallace over Johnson's signing of the Civil Rights act, which ended Jim Crow laws supported by Southern Democrats.

If we go with Humphrey was liked as much as Johnson and take the 68 election state votes (States won, not electors), the best guess is that Johnson was popular in only 13 states, plus D.C. (Maine, Mass, RI, CT, NY, PA, MD, WV, MI, TX, MN, OR, HI).

Answer (score 0):

As for Vietnam there are some statistics from diferend years:

[image]

[image]

[image]

So as can be seen on the graphics there were changes during the years.

Comment: The question is asking for a breakdown in those ratings per US state, such as New York, Kentucky, etc. rather than different stages of the war.

Comment: @JJJ Sorry looks like I mised that. Is my answer now offtopic? Should I delete it?

Comment: Yea I think you might as well. Or edit / reanswer if you find polling data which does break it down by state. :P